# Retrieve SQL entries from Django login

Tags: python, sql, django, django-forms

I'm new to Django. I wrote a login script using the built-in `User` models.

```
def login_user(request):
    state = "Please login below..."
    username = password = ''
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                state = "You're successfully logged in!"
                return render_to_response('home.html',{'username': username})
            else:
                state = "Your account is not active, please contact the site admin."
        else:
            state = "Your username and/or password were incorrect."

    return render_to_response('index.html',{'state':state})
```

This opens a new page `home` where I display the `{{username}}`.
However, how can I retrieve other values like `id`,`email`,`fullname` etc. of that particular `username` from `database` and display them on my `home` page. I've tried using `User.objects.all()`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already *have* the user object, ([`authenticate()` returns it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate)), so just retrieve information from `user`. See the [`User` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#user-objects) to see what you can get from it:

```
# ...
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user is not None:
    if user.is_active:
        state = "You're successfully logged in!"
        info = dict(username=username, email=user.email, fullname=user.get_full_name())
        return render_to_response('home.html', info)
```

Comment: @xan It's probably worth mentioning that django can provide the user as a variable to all templates using the built in (when enabled in settings) context processors: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth

Comment: @xan: Pass in the whole `user` object and access it's methods and attributes in the template, or use the context processor Josh pointed you to. To query articles, use the standard query API from Django.